# Unable to test against Safari using v1.18.0

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I just updated to TestCafe v1.18.0 and I followed the upgrade guide. I am able to run tests against Chrome and Firefox, as the system correctly prompted me if I wanted to let TestCafe control these, but this is not happening for Safari, so I am unable to test against it. I don't see any way to manually add an entry in the Automation tab either.

[Automation Tab entry for TestCafe Browser Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjrNW.png)

Edit: I managed to add it using the `remote` option for TestCafe and pasting the URL into Safari, but even after that, `npx testcafe safari` is unable to launch Safari. I'm using an M1 Mac and macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe 1.18.0 does have the Safari-related issue. It has already been fixed. Please update TestCafe to v1.18.1.